# input parameter in addition to variadic template arguments failed to compile

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I put effort to write the example step by step to make it clear and simple to understand.

The object BaseCreator shown here exposes a create function which uses an internal class NewObject to allocate a new object of type T. The class NewObject default method is the usual way of using new operator, but it can be changed using specialization to use different process. We will see it later.

```
template <typename F>
class BaseCreator
{
public:
    BaseCreator() = default;
    virtual ~BaseCreator() = default;

    // create function 
    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    std::shared_ptr<T> create(Args&&... parameters)
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(NewObject<T, Args...>().get(std::forward<Args>(parameters)...));
    }

private:
    // creator object with default functionality to create a new object
    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    struct NewObject
    {
        T* get(Args&&... parameters)
        {
            return new T(std::forward<Args>(parameters)...);
        }
    };
};
```

This works nice, and for example  assume we have the follow objects types:

```
struct A
{
    A(int i_i, const std::string& i_s) : i(i_i), s(i_s) {}
    void addVal(int i_i) { i+=i_i; }
    int i = 0;
    std::string s;
};

struct B
{
    B(const std::vector<float>& i_v) : v(i_v) {}
    void addVal(int i_i) { v.push_back((float)i_i); }
    std::vector<float> v;
};
```

we can create them easily , for example:

```
// declare type for a creator identity 
struct Group111 {};

// creator object
BaseCreator<Group111> cCreator111;

// creating A and B
std::shared_ptr<A> spA = cCreator111.create<A>(5, "Hello");
std::shared_ptr<B> spB = cCreator111.create<B>(std::vector<float>({ 0.5f,0.1f,0.7f,0.9f }));
```

We can also declare a specific creation method for a specific object and specific type of creator. Here for example a specialization for creating object A using a creator of Group222:

```
// declare type for a creator identity 
struct Group222 {};

// specialize NewObject for BaseCreator<Group222> for creating A
template<> 
template< typename... Args> 
struct BaseCreator<Group222>::NewObject<A, Args...>
{
    A* get(int i_factor, int i_i, const std::string& i_s)
    {
        A* p = new A(i_i, i_s);
        p->i *= i_factor;
        return p;
    }
};
```

And creating object A using a creator of type Group222 will have a different method than the default one.

```
// creator object
BaseCreator<Group222> cCreator222;

// creating A with creator of Group222 needs now additional input argument 
std::shared_ptr<A> spA = cCreator222.create<A>(3, 5, "Hello");

// creating A with creator of Group222 is the same as creating using creator cCreator111
std::shared_ptr<B> spB = cCreator222.create<B>(std::vector<float>({ 0.5f,0.1f,0.7f,0.9f }));
```

And now for the problem :)

Now, I want to derive a new BaseCreator to have the follow one, which as you can see, has proxy create function and call its base class one with additional integer to the pack:

```
class Creator333 : public BaseCreator<Creator333>
{
public:
    Creator333() = default;
    virtual ~Creator333() = default;

    // creator
    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    std::shared_ptr<T> create(Args&&... parameters)
    {
        int adder = 5; // just for the example
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(BaseCreator<Creator333>::create<T>(adder, std::forward<Args>(parameters)...));
    }

};
```

It comes with its specialized `BaseCreator<Creator333>::NewObject` which should handle this additional integer for any object (in this example - assuming the object has a member function called addVal())

```
template<> 
template<typename T, typename... Args> 
struct BaseCreator<Creator333>::NewObject<T, Args...>
{
    T* get(int i_adder, Args&&... parameters)
    {
        T* p = new T(std::forward<Args>(parameters)...);
        p->addVal(i_adder);
        return p;
    }
};
```

If I will try to create an object, lets say B using this Creator333:

```
Creator333 cCreator333;

// creation of B using Creator333 
std::shared_ptr<B> spB3 = cCreator333.create<B>(std::vector<float>({ 0.1f,0.2f}));
```

I will get a compiler error:

```
error C2660: 'BaseCreator<Creator333>::NewObject<T,int &,_Ty>::get': function does not take 2 arguments
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=B,
1>            _Ty=std::vector<float,std::allocator<float>>
1>        ]
```

But this is strange, because the function indeed should get two arguments as follows:

1. `Create333::create`  - gets a pack with one element  std::vector({ 0.1f,0.2f})
2. It calls its base calss `BaseCreator<Create333>::create` with additional integer, thus
   `BaseCreator<Create333>::create` get a pack with two elements : int(5) and  std::vector({ 0.1f,0.2f})
3. ``` BaseCreator<Create333>::create`` calls ```  BaseCreator::NewObject.get``` where the first element of the pack goes for the get(adder, and the other element of the pack goes for the get(Args ...

So what is the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that the overload resolution doesn’t work the way you think it does, or, perhaps more to the point, you think that there’s overload resolution where there’s none it’d look like (or vice versa). I don’t think this design will work as shown, but I have only glanced at it. Looks like a very familiar problem. I’m sure this question is a duplicate. Google for something like *overload resolution and template parameter packs* or some such.

Comment: Thanks @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica, your suggestion helped  - see below my answer, but if you understand why, It will make it perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The follow is a solution but not an answer,
which means the code works, but I don't understand why this work and the one in the question doesn't. So if there someone that can describe the reason, I'm sure it will help many to understand more deeply about the subject.

Thanks to @Kuba comment I did a search according to the words he suggested and found a code in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051645/is-a-c11-variadic-function-template-overload-with-a-dependent-type-ambiguous) which inspired me for the follow solution:

I added a `Helper` class for `Creator333` as follows. It helps to split an input pack into the desired two parts: the additional integer and the original pack came from the application code. But I had also to move the special creation code into it.

```
class Creator333 : public BaseCreator<Creator333>
{
public:
    Creator333() = default;
    virtual ~Creator333() = default;

    // creator
    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    std::shared_ptr<T> create(Args&&... parameters)
    {
        int adder = 5; // just for the example
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(BaseCreator<Creator333>::create<T>(adder, std::forward<Args>(parameters)...));
    }

    // helper class for splitting given pack into  desired two parts: 
    // the additional integer and the original pack came from the application code
    template<typename T, typename FirstTypeT, typename... Args>
    struct Helper
    {
        T* get(FirstTypeT i_adder, Args&&... parameters)
        {
            T* p = new T(std::forward<Args>(parameters)...);
            p->addVal(i_adder);
            return p;
        }
    };
};
```

The specialization `BaseCreator<Creator333>::NewObject` itself now just need to use the Helper as shown:

```
template<> 
template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct BaseCreator<Creator333>::NewObject<T, Args...>
{
    T* get(Args&&... parameters)
    {
        return Creator333::Helper<T,Args... >().get(std::forward<Args>(parameters)...);
    }
};
```